# Android Layout View is invisible

Tags: android, xml, layout

[image: Layout Preview]

That's the preview in Android Studio. Everything is fine. The red bar on the left is visible. But it is invisible on the device. After 6 hours of pain I'm asking for help. It is a row in a list view in a fragment in an activity.

Update: If I set the layout_height to a constant e.g. 50dp it becomes visible. Else the height of the view is 0. How to match the height to the parent?

Here is the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >
    <View
        android:id="@+id/owner_indicator"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_red">
    </View>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/owner_indicator"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/upvote_button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/upvote_button"
        android:paddingBottom="33dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:tint="@color/main_color"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_time_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/camera_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_photo"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/owner_indicator"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:tint="@color/main_color"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_time_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_time"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/camera_image"
        />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/main_color"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/time_label"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="@string/upvote"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/vote_button_states"
        android:id="@+id/upvote_button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="upvoteTouched"/>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/main_color"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/rating_label"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upvote_button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="@string/downvote"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:src="@drawable/vote_button_states"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/downvote_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rating_label"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/upvote_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/upvote_button"
        android:onClick="downvoteTouched"/>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/light_gray"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/comments_label"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/time_label"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/time_label"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/time_label"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/downvote_button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/downvote_button"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: move `View` with `owner_indicator` id after `TextView` with `comments_label` id

Comment: thank you but still invisible

Comment: Try to active "display contours" and look at if you see your red bar.

Comment: Try to add below properties to your view 


    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"